# Joomla session related issue that changes on every refresh

Tags: joomla

My `session.save_path` is '/var/lib/php/session'. But every time on page refresh session_id and csrf token is changing in Joomla, for which I cannot login to admin panel. Session save path permission is apache:apache 777. Please help. Joomla version 3.6 php 5.4.16. My session.cookie_secure is true

Comment: Try using another save path for your sessions. See: http://www.itoctopus.com/how-to-fix-joomlas-problem-with-session-save_path . If that doesn't fix it, then please post back here.

Comment: I changed the session save path by ini_set(), same result. I am using http, so if my session.cookie_secure is on, will it results in new session id?